# Reverse for 'create-ordercontent' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['store/create\\-ordercontent/(?P<order_id>[^/]+)$']

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I'm newer for Django. I'm trying to pass a id from 1st url to 2nd ur.

> Reverse for 'create-ordercontent' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['store/create\-ordercontent/(?P<order_id>[^/]+)$']

urls.py

```
path('list-ordercontent/<order_id>', OrdercontentListView.as_view(), name='list-ordercontent'),
path('create-ordercontent/<order_id>', create_ordercontent, name='create-ordercontent'),
```

view.py

```
class OrdercontentListView(ListView):
    model = Ordercontent
    template_name = 'store/list_ordercontent.html'
    context_object_name = 'ordercontent'

    def get_queryset(self):
        model = Ordercontent
        order = self.request.resolver_match.kwargs['order_id']
        return model.objects.filter(order=order)
```

in list-ordercontent.html, I tried to use same order_id to pass the variable I wanted, but it' incorrect. I want to know how to use the order_id into the another url, in my program it's the url for creating.

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
<div class="breadcrumbs-inner">
    <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="page-header float-left">
                <div class="page-title">
                    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="page-header float-right">
                <div class="page-title">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb text-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Order</a></li>
                        <li class="active">
                            <a>{{ ordercontent.order.id }}</a>
                            <a>Content</a>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xl-12">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="box-title float-left">
                <h4>Order Content</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="box-title float-right">
                <a href="{% url 'create-ordercontent' order_id %}">Add Product</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body--">
            <div class="table-stats order-table ov-h">
                <table class="table ">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="serial">#</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Type</th>
                            <th>Supplier</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {% if ordercontent %}
                        {% for ordercontent in ordercontent %}
                        <tr>
                            <td class="serial">{{ ordercontent.order.id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ ordercontent.product.name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ ordercontent.product.ptype }}</td>
                            <td>{{ ordercontent.product.supplier }}</td>
                            <td>{{ ordercontent.amount }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% else %}
                            <tr><td>No Content</td></tr>
                        {% endif %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div> <!-- /.table-stats -->
        </div>
    </div> <!-- /.card -->
</div>  <!-- /.col-lg-8 -->
```

Comment: What error are you facing ?? Can you add more information.

Comment: When I try to open the url, create-ordercontent. the error is

Reverse for 'create-ordercontent' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['store/create\\-ordercontent/(?P<order_id>[^/]+)$']

Comment: show your template full code  **<a href="{% url 'create-ordercontent' order_id %}">Add Product</a>** this one

Comment: Yes. I showed my full code.

Comment: From where you have taken this **order_id** variable

Comment: I took the variable is from 'list-ordercontent/<order_id>'. When I show the ordercontent, I have already took the order_id from the url, and apply it in the OrdercontentListView

Comment: `ordercontent in ordercontent` _fire in the hole_

Comment: actually the ordercontent in ordercontent is good for running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListView` does not add the keyword arguments received by the view to the context, if you want them to be in the context, you should add them yourself by overriding `get_context_data`:

```python
class OrdercontentListView(ListView):
    model = Ordercontent
    template_name = 'store/list_ordercontent.html'
    context_object_name = 'ordercontent'

    def get_queryset(self):
        model = Ordercontent
        order = self.kwargs['order_id'] # No need to access `request.resolver_match.kwargs` they are present in `self.kwargs`
        return model.objects.filter(order=order)
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['order_id'] = self.kwargs['order_id']
        return context
```